# java string to json conversion using json lib

Tags: java, json-lib

Issue here that while converting to json object decimal value get truncated. I'm using Json-lib for below code.

```
String str = "{'key':'key','type':'string','value':9276658.1}";
JSONObject fromObject = JSONObject.fromObject(str);
// sysout -> output {"key":"key","type":"string","value":9276658}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: When do you get that "output"? Post code that produces that output. You probably need to read `value` as `double`.

Comment: I already tried that and it returns value = 9276658.0 [fromObject.getDouble("value")]

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/json-lib/bugs/116/

Comment: Use Gson instead.